# nothing inserting with ajax post mvc4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Nothing is being inserted even when I hard code the values. Can I use the method that was created when I created the Transaction class or do I have to write a custom method for an ajax call?

jQuery/ajax call

```
$("#SubmitTransaction").on("click", function () {
var div = $("#AddedItems");

var uid = $("#getUser").attr("data-logName");
var TUid = $("#uid").attr("data-tID");
var TId = $('#TiD').attr("data-tID");
var ids = $("#AddedItems li").map(function () { return this.id }).get();

var trade = {
    FromUserID: uid,
    TID: TUid,
    itemTForId: TItemId,
    items: ids
}
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Transaction/Create",
    data: trade

   });
});
```

Controller: I figured if I passed a `Transaction` it would be ok

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Transactions transaction)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Transactions.Add(transaction);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(transactions);//not really concerned with where it goes right now
    }                             //just want to get the values in the db
```

Transaction model

```
       public class Transactions
{


    // all the properties
    //
    //
    public ICollection<Item> items { get; set; }//this is not being stored

}
```

Comment: Try to pass `trade` in action parameter variable name

Comment: public ActionResult Create(Transactions trade)

Comment: oh in the `actionResult`. I was confused as to what you were saying

Comment: no, nothing. nulls all around

Comment: Try one more thing, pass as $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Transaction/Create",
    data: JSON.stringify(trade)

   });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute, your ajax request ***must*** contain the token generated by `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`. For example: this is your form:

```
<form>
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

//other field
</form>
```

@Html.AntiForgeryToken() by default will render a hidden field with `name="__RequestVerificationToken"`. You could try your ajax as follows:

```
var trade = {
    FromUserID: uid,
    ToUserID: TUid,
    itemTradedForId: TItemId,
    items: ids,
    __RequestVerificationToken: $("[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val()
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Transaction/Create",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',                     
    data: JSON.stringify(trade)
   });
});
```

Also specify `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` and `JSON.stringify(trade)`

Comment: is that passed in the trade object or in one of the post variables?

Comment: ok, that puts values into the transaction table but the `ids` aren't being stored. When I output the values with an `alert` to make sure something is being sent I get this `ids = ,,4,5`. What's with those two commas before the 4? Happens with all values

Comment: I added my transaction class with the ICollection. Those are not being stored

Comment: @healix: problem could be this line `$("#AddedItems li").map(function () { return this.id }).get();`. Please check what you're trying here. (there could be `li` with empty value)

Comment: I have a `<li>` that grabs the logged in user.

Comment: @healix: check why there are `li`s with empty value

Comment: ok, pulled the  `<li>` that gets the UserID but now nothing posts

Comment: could it be where I have the `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`? I don't have a form

Comment: @healix: yes, just put it anywhere on the html page if you don't have a form.

Comment: heres the thing. When I take out `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',data: JSON.stringify(trade)` values are put into the transaction table but still nothing in the collections table